# rails 3.1 dynamic controller instantiation

Tags: ruby, reflection, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems, rails-engines

I have a Rails Engine gem in which I want to load a HomeController class definition dynamically from an initializer. I can instantiate the class correctly, but when I go to call the index action, I get this error :

```
TypeError in HomeController#index

can't convert nil into String
Rails.root: /home/chris/test_app

Full Trace:
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_view/template/resolver.rb:16:in `<<'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_view/template/resolver.rb:16:in `build'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_view/template/resolver.rb:127:in `find_templates'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_view/template/resolver.rb:45:in `find_all'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_view/template/resolver.rb:76:in `cached'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_view/template/resolver.rb:44:in `find_all'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_view/path_set.rb:21:in `find_all'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_view/path_set.rb:20:in `each'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_view/path_set.rb:20:in `find_all'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_view/path_set.rb:19:in `each'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_view/path_set.rb:19:in `find_all'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_view/path_set.rb:29:in `exists?'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_view/lookup_context.rb:94:in `template_exists?'
```

I cut the trace off after the actionpack part because it was really long, but I think this is all the relevant information.

Here is my Engine class definition:

```
module MyGem
   class Engine < Rails::Engine

      initializer 'my_gem.load_middleware' do |app|
        home_controller = create_controller 'HomeController'
      end

      def create_controller(class_name, &block)
        klass = Class.new ApplicationController, &block
        Object.const_set class_name, klass
        return klass
      end
   end
end
```

this is when i have the root path set to home#index . if I create a home_controller.rb in app/controllers in either the application or the gem like so:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
end
```

then everything works fine and the index action is rendered appropriately, so I'm sure there is no problem with my routes, views, or application controller.

Any light shed on this issue would be much appreciated.
*edit*
the output of

`HomeController.view_paths.join " : "`

is

`/home/chris/gems/my_gem/app/views : /home/chris/test_app/app/views`

Comment: That line is trying to build a path to the template, based the view's name.  For some reason the view's name is `nil` here, and ActionView doesn't check to be safe (it does check `empty?` on other values, but no the name of the view).

Comment: Does `klass.name` show you what you expect? (i.e. HomeController)

Comment: Also, are you able to access it as `::HomeController` (with the global namespace prefix)?  Shouldn't it actually be defined under your engine's module, rather than in the top-level namespace?

Comment: yes, klass.name shows HomeController. I can access ::HomeController.

Comment: and, i tried instantiating HomeController in the module first, but the ApplicationController wasn't loaded at that point. so I moved the create_class to an initializer in the engine class. I figured this was better than requiring application_controller.rb in the module file for the gem.

Comment: do you think this is a bug in the framework possibly? or is there some attribute of HomeController (or instances thereof) that I could set to fix this? view_path is not null, I'm adding the output of view_path to the question..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3769/discussion-between-chris-drappier-and-d11wtq)

Comment: you're not passing any block to create_controller()....?

Comment: not in this instance, this is a simple example to illustrate the issue at hand.

Comment: Do you mind to post the controller definition in initializer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure where you get the DSL "initializer" from... but that seems to cause a problem. It doesn't get executed on new()

This seems to work for me in Rails 3.0.7:

```
module MyGem
   class Engine < Rails::Engine

     def initialize
        home_controller = create_controller 'HomeController'
     end

# this doesn't seem to do anything...
#
#      initializer 'my_gem.load_middleware' do |app|
#        home_controller = create_controller 'HomeController'
#      end

      def create_controller(class_name, &block)
        klass = Class.new ApplicationController::Base , &block # shouldn't this be ApplicationController::Base ?

#        Object.const_set class_name, klass     # module of superclass is ApplicationController, not Object

        ApplicationController.const_set(class_name, klass)  # name of the module containing superclass
        puts "Klass created! : #{Object.constants}"
        return klass
      end
   end
end
```

and running the code:

```
 h = MyGem::Engine.new
Klass created! : [:Object, :Module, :Class, :Kernel, :NilClass, :NIL, :Data, :TrueClass, :TRUE, :FalseClass, :FALSE, :Encoding ... :BasicObject]
 => #<MyGem::Engine:0x00000006de9878> 


> ApplicationController.const_get("HomeController")
 => ApplicationController::HomeController
```

Comment: lol, I can't believe I didn't try that before. I'll check it this weekend when I get a chance to get back on this project. thanks for answering!

Comment: I read about the initializers here : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/initialization.html towards the bottom of the page

Comment: if i set it up that way, then start the test/dummy application generated inside of the gem, then i get uninitialized constant on the Application controller when i start the server. but the way I have it, the server will start and I get my error when i try to render the action